# CSS transition not working with scale(0) + hardware acceleration in chrome 45?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, animation

CSS transitions don't work when hardware acceleration is activated (either via `will-change` or via `translateZ(0)`) and you are animating to or from `scale(0)` in chrome 45. (Version 45.0.2454.85 (64-bit))

(Firefox 40 works with `will-change`, but not with `translateZ(0)`)

**DEMO**: http://codepen.io/zapdev/pen/ojbdVb 
(enable hardware acceleration and the hide animation stops working)

My current work around:

```
.hide {
    transform: scale(0.0002);
    opcacity: 0;
    transition: transform 400ms, opacity 0ms 400ms;
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

**EDIT:**
I am on MacOS X and my WebGL Renderer is `"Intel Iris Pro OpenGL Engine"`

Also: `Chrome 47.0.2511.0 canary (64-bit)` works (like Firefox 40) with `will-change`, but not with `translateZ(0)`. Looks like `will-change` is generally the way to go for hardware acceleration.

Comment: A new version was released 45.0.2454.93 m. Try to update ur browser.I've opened your codepen and everything is looking good in the above mentioned version (with hardware acceleration enabled). Hope this helps, cheers

Comment: Still not working for me on 45.0.2454.93 (i don't have a `m` at the end). I am   on Mac btw.

Comment: sorry to hear that... I've tested on win7 64-bit. Assuming that your code is well written, try to open a ticket here https://www.chromium.org/  Report bugs section if you have not done this already.

Comment: Tested on `Google Chrome 45.0.2454.99 m` on Windows 7; it works!

Answer (score 2):

The browser doesnt know how to read transform override.
when you use transform:translateZ('value'); you are override the scale.

for it to work you need to initial all div with scale and translateZ, and this way it will work in all ways.

[VIEW DEMO](http://codepen.io/elad2412/pen/ojBWEO)

```
div{
  transition: transform 400ms;
  transform:scale(1) translateZ(0);
}

div:hover{
  transform: scale(1.4) translateZ(0);
}

div.hide{
  transform: scale(0) translateZ(0);
}
```

Comment: Your example works, however the issue was not that the scale was overridden. (If that were the issue also the hover transition would have failed.) The issue is that it can't interpolate, because matrix interpolation can't invert the `scale(0)` keyframe. more information: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=535094#c6